# How can I deserialize Retrofit response with Gson to different List types?

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I register a TypeAdapter when I build my Retrofit instance, which delegates all API calls expecting a List response:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl("$baseURL/")
                .addConverterFactory(
                        GsonConverterFactory.create(
                                GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(List::class.java, MatchesDeserializer()) //Delegates all calls expecting return of type List.
                                        .registerTypeAdapter(Array<String>::class.java, PhotoDeserializer()) //This works, because it's a different type.
                                        .registerTypeAdapter(Triple::class.java, ChatMessagesDeserializer())
                                        .create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
                .build()
```

Right now, the only calls I make expect a List of the same type (User, which requires the custom Deserializer), but I want to be able to make calls returning Lists of different types (say Item, which is automatically deserialized). The problem is that I can't specify which List type the MatchesDeserializer should be used for, as a class literal can't include type information. We *can* specify type for an Array response without issues.

```
GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(List<String>::class.java, MatchesDeserializer()) //This doesn't compile.
```

I could change all calls expecting List to return JsonObject, and parse it with my deserializer manually, or implement a TypeAdapterFactory to manually deserialize only User types.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I'am pretty sure it should work: `GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type, yourDeserializer())`. (if it works give me info, so I will try describe why :D )

Comment: @Cililing the deserializer is not called at all if I use this method, although it does compile.